# Black screen when pushing view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.navigationController.storyboard;
DetailTrickEnter *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailTrickEnter"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

'Storyboard () doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'DetailTrickEnter''

In the storyboard there is a viewcontroller with name I checked it very precisely.
Help with it.thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is because you are supposed to go to the storyboard and then select your view controller and on the right go to the tab that says storyboard ID and type: DetailTrickEnter

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set Storyboard identifier  `Storyboard ID: DetailTrickEnter`

[image]